# Load Multiple Templates Dynamically in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

How to load multiple templates in `Meteor JS` ? I know how to load a single template dynamically. But not getting to load multiple Templates.Please see the below code of loading single template & suggest me what to do for Load Multiple Templates?

JS Code :

```
Meteor.startup(function () 
  {
    Session.set('currentTemplate', 'login');
  });
Template.content.helpers
({
    'renderTemplate': function()
    {
       if(Session.get('currentTemplate') == undefined)
       {
         Session.set('currentTemplate', 'login');
       }
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')]({dataKey: '0'}));
    }
 })
```

Comment: You may want to consider using a [router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a template inside another one:

```
<template name="oneTemplate">
  {{> anotherTemplate}}
</template>
```

To load a different template depending on the url, it's better to use [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router).